# AngleSharp | System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, парсер, null, visual-studio-2019, anglesharp

Только начал изучать **c#** поэтому пока что балуюсь параллельно изучая основы.
Решил написать парсер для одного сайта, с помощью **AngleSharp** библиотеки.

Есть вот такой код взятый с документации

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var address = "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google";
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
var google = document.QuerySelector("div.mw-parser-output ul li:nth-child(5)").TextContent;
```

Который работает и выдает ожидаемый результат "Google — слово английского языка."
Но стоит мне заменить допустим **:nth-child(5)** на **:nth-child(6)**

То получаю ошибку на 5 строке:

[image: ошибка]

Я понимаю что этого нет на сайте, но я ожидал получить null и уже дальше самому решать что с этим делать. Потому что на моем сайте не на всех страницах существуют теги которые я собираюсь парсить.

Comment: А вы и получили null но только вы сделали null.TextContext - т.е. не указали, что делать с null. Вариантов два. Либо записать строку в форме `var google = document.QuerySelector("div.mw-parser-output ul li:nth-child(5)")?.TextContent;` либо убрать .TextContent и проверить на null в следующей строке и решать что и как с этим null делать. По факту, вы ДУМАЕТЕ что знаете как работает код, но на деле - нет. Вы именно в коде указали "я не хочу решать, что делать с null, тут его не будет". А он вдруг - есть!

Comment: вы и получаете `null`, но после этого вы пытаетесь у `null` вызвать свойство `TextContent` что и приводит к исключению. Для того, что бы это работало так, как вы ожидаете вы можете исользовать оператор знак вопроса: `document.QuerySelector("div.mw-parser-output ul li:nth-child(5)")?.TextContent`

Comment: Вот ещё объяснение. По факту пятая строка содержит в себе две строки. Первая `var element = document.QuerySelector("div.mw-parser-output ul li:nth-child(5)")` и вторая `var elementContent = element.TextContent;` и вы не видите эту склеенность двух строк. Поставьте после первой `if(element == null)` и вот тогда будет видно, что хотите решать что с этим null делать. Пока что в показанном коде видно, что писавший не ожидает никак null. Ожидающий null поставит ? перед .TextContent